# chrome disable omnibox searches webhelper.centurylink.com

Tags: google-chrome, omnibox

If I type "news" and another word, I'm trying to have the chrome omnibox do a search for "another word"

What I get instead is an "auto complete" search that results in this website:

http://webhelper.centurylink.com/index_results.php?querybox=another+word&submit=Web+Search

How do I get rid of this apparent browser hijack?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is an "auto detected" search engine from earlier browsing (in this case, centurylink's "auto redir on host not found" system) that google has "found" and now uses for the word "news", assuming that if I type in "news" followed by a space, I want to "search that site for the next word" (yikes).

Fix: go to chrome://settings/ -> manage search engines -> search for "centurylink" or "news" (it will be under other search engines) and remove it.